Azure Data Factory (ADF) dataflow picks up incorrect Integration runtime when I manually trigger it
I have created a pipeline which triggers the execution of a dataflow.
`
When I click the debug button of the pipeline the execution of the dataflow is successful. I manually specify the needed integration runtime, which is custom and obviously it is the same I pick for the Data flow debug setting.



The I publish/deploy my ADF changes via an Azure pipeline (SQLPlayer.DataFactoryTools.PublishADF.PublishADFTask@2) and trigger the same pipeline manually.

I realized that for some reason it picks up the incorrect (AutoResolveIntegrationR) integration runtime and gives me an error: Can not connect to ... which is expected as the linked services are configured to use the custom Integration runtime

Any ideas on based on what logic it picks Integration runtimes and how I can configure it?

Not only in linked service configuration, you might need to select the desired Integration runtime to be used in the Dataflow activity settings , kindly select the right IR and run the dataflow and see if it works :


I had already done this, but it was still picking up the wrong Integration Runtime. Thanks for your reply though @AnnuKumari
